# Alter doesn't show in processlist

Tags: mysql, alter-table, process

I'm performing an alter. It's currently running on a large table (300,000,000).

```
MariaDB [my_database]> ALTER TABLE my_table
    -> add INDEX a (x, y, z),
    -> add INDEX d (x);
Stage: 1 of 2 'copy to tmp table'   60.1% of stage done
```

But the processlist doesn't mention it, with repeated queries.

```
MariaDB [my_database]> show full processlist;
+----+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
| Id | User | Host            | db          | Command | Time | State | Info                  | Progress |
+----+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
|  6 | apps | localhost:52235 | my_database | Sleep   |  304 |       | NULL                  |    0.000 |
| 33 | apps | localhost       | my_database | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show full processlist |    0.000 |
+----+------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I would expect it to show up. Any ideas why not?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the user that's executing the `ALTER TABLE` and the user who's running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` are not the same user, and the second user lacks the `PROCESS` privilege.

> If you have the `PROCESS` privilege, you can see all threads. Otherwise, you can see only your own threads (that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using).
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html</sup>

Comment: You're right, thanks. I had too many shells open and wasn't trying this with the correct user.